# ObjC method type encoding string for a method with a Block parameter

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime, method-signature

I'm reading
Apple's [article about Objective-C runtime type encoding strings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html) but I do not understand how to encode a method with a Block parameter.

For example, I have this :

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
```

I don't understand what to use for `(void(^)())completionHandler`

Comment: Maybe it will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172758/encoding-an-objective-c-block

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly?  Depending on context, the answer will vary.

Answer (score 1):

All object types are `@`. Therefore I would expect this, because blocks are objects in Objective-C.

However, you can ask the runtime itself with `method_getTypeEncoding()`.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, use the `@encode` directive:

```
typedef void(^CompletionHandler)(void);

char *encoded = @encode(CompletionHandler);
NSLog(@"Encoded: %s", encoded);
```

prints `@?`.

To quote your documentation link:

> @   An object (whether statically typed or typed id)
>   ? An unknown type (among other things, this code is used for function pointers)

Comment: `@encode()` emits different encodings than the compiler does for methods.  This may not answer OP's question.

Comment: @bbum Really? I also tried `method_getTypeEncoding()` and I got the same result.

Comment: `@encode` doesn't include the (now bogus) stack offsets.